# Why isn't Daenerys searching for more dragon eggs?

Tags: game-of-thrones

As stated during *Game of Thrones* season 1:

> The only thing left of the race are petrified dragon eggs

There is a possibility of more eggs existing. Why hasn't Daenerys tasked other to search for more dragon eggs?

Comment: dragon eggs can't be found on supermarket

Comment: Posting as a comment as I don't feel I have enough to answer this question, and I'm not sure the question really belongs here. I believe the reason is that Daenerys simply isn't a greedy person. The only thing she wants is the throne, as she believes that it belongs to her, but she's really an empathic and generous person, so it's not really in her nature to greed for more than what she's already got. Her three dragons are also like children to her, and one doesn't really just go out and look for new ones.

Answer (score 19):

Because the night her dragons hatched was [*magic*](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Magic)...

> The birth of Dany's dragons was unique, magical, wonderous, a miracle. She is called The Unburnt because she walked into the flames and lived.

Dragons have been always been associated with magic. It said that magic died when the dragons did. Hence it would take magic to bring them back.

The night Daenrys lights the funeral pyre for Khal Drogo is the same night the "Bleeding Star" appears.  Without the right magical conditions, trying to find dragon eggs so that you can hatch them is a fools errand as many of the Targaryens proved over the years...

For more background (from the books) on the magic it took to hatch the eggs you can see [this answer on SFF.](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/159026/was-daenerys-actually-trying-to-hatch-the-eggs/159029#159029) So knowing the high price it takes to hatch the eggs, there is no need to find more as she is not willing to pay that price again.

Comment: So your answer is basically that she doesn't think it's worth the time? Better things to do?

Comment: @TheFamousDirector No, his answer is basically that `Without the right magical conditions, trying to hatch a dragon's egg is a fools errand`. Kind of unfair of you to just disregard his entire answer like that, merely because it doesn't satisfy you personally.

Comment: @GhotiandChips How are my questions and his answer that different? I am just asking for clarification.

Comment: Its a good answer but don't know if it is true for both the books and the show. In the show it wasn't that clear that these conditions needed to be fulfilled.

Comment: It is not explicit as "thou shalt use your husband corpse to hatch thy egg", but it is clear that hatching egg is difficult and not without risk (i am looking at you summerhall). Plus, the funeral pyre (and the fact that she survive) is clearly linked to magic

Comment: Upvoted, but IIRC the "bleeding star" was already up in the sky in S1E1, or at least had been for a long while when the eggs hatched.

Comment: @Mat'sMug Just because we see it earlier in the episode somewhere else doesn't mean it was visible to Dany. The scenes are not necessarily in chronological order .

Comment: Pretty sure (like, 99.9%) it was up in the sky all along her pregnancy.

Comment: @Mat'sMug [we do not see it until S2E1](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Red_Comet)

Comment: Ha, I stand corrected!

Comment: But the thing is. Do Daenerys knows that all that was required to hatch the eggs? Or does she think that entering the fire with the eggs was enough?

Comment: @TheFamousDirector The difference is you are actually trying to make his answer fit the question. The question is about searching for and finding eggs, while this answer is about hatching them.

Comment: If she's not going to hatch them, why would she want to find them?